# Handling non-nullable reference type when conditions are not met to construct it

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I wanted to create a *safe* class that checks the values provided to it for validity, so that later when working with an instance, I have to write fewer checks.

```
public class FerryArguments
{
    private readonly string? _sourceDirectory;

    public string SourceDirectory { get => _sourceDirectory!; init { if (!Directory.Exists(value)) { throw new ArgumentException("Source directory does not exist"); } _sourceDirectory = value; } }

    public Uri ServiceUrl { get; init; }

    public FerryArguments(string srouceDirectory, Uri serviceUrl)
    {
        SourceDirectory = srouceDirectory;
        ServiceUrl = serviceUrl;
    }
}
```

When instantiating `FerryArguments`, it makes sure the directory exists.

Using this in a console app for example, I would read the command line arguments, check if everything is provided, and then construct `FerryArguments`.

I can't figure out how to parse and return in a single call, because if something is wrong with the command line arguments, I can't return a valid `FerryArguments` instance:

```
FerryArguments GetFerryArgs(string[] args)
{
    // no way to fail cleanly
}
```

Same thing if I do a "TryParse"-style approach:

```
bool TryGetFerryArgs(string[] args, out FerryArguments ferryArgs)
{
    var arglist = args.ToList();
    var dirIndex = arglist.IndexOf("-d");
    var webIndex = arglist.IndexOf("-s");

    if (dirIndex == -1)
    {
        ferryArgs = // can't assign anything
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) you can use to instruct the compiler in scenarios such as yours?  In particular, look at the `TryGetMessage` example -- basically, you make the parameter nullable, but the attribute instructs the compiler that if you return true, the parameter will not be null.

Comment: As a side note, your constructor takes those two arguments to initialize the properties, but there's nothing preventing the properties from being set again in an object initializer. The `init` accessors are not useful here. Remove them (and move the validation into the constructor itself) and the properties can be read-only, auto-implemented (i.e. `{ get; }`). It's also worth noting that a directory could be renamed or deleted during the lifetime of the object, so the check at construction isn't the final word on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version (`GetFerryArgs`) you might just throw an exception as that's what is going to happen anyway if the arguments are badly formed. Another option would be to return a nullable value and check for null on the call site.

In the second version (`TryGetFerryArgs`) the out parameter should be nullable:

```
bool TryGetFerryArgs(string[] args, [NotNullWhen(true)] out FerryArguments? ferryArgs)
{
    var arglist = args.ToList();
    var dirIndex = arglist.IndexOf("-d");
    var webIndex = arglist.IndexOf("-s");

    if (dirIndex == -1)
    {
        ferryArgs = null;
        return false;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

The `NotNullWhen` attribute tells the compiler that the null-state of the `ferryArgs` parameter depends on the return value of the method.

Comment: yup, this is the solution I went with